# Google maps get geojson data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson

#### How to get current marker position as geojson?

I have working google maps code but i need to transform google maps `latLng` coordinates format to geojson

```
submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let geojson = getGeoJsonSomehow(this.marker.getPosition());
    this.updateData({location: geojson}).then(...).catch(this.setError)
}
```

Type of geometry - `Point`

Geojson format: http://geojson.org/

Comment: Use **google.maps.Data** class then you can get the geojson.

Comment: Thanks, but how i can pass Marker position to map Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the geoJson of the marker by creating the Point feature as below.

```
submitHandler(e) {
    //Your code
    var point = new google.maps.Data.Feature({
        geometry : new google.maps.Data.Point(this.marker.getPosition())
    });
    var geoJson = "";
    point.toGeoJson(function(json) {
        geoJson = JSON.stringify(json)
        console.log(geoJson);
    });
    //geoJson variable will have the required json string.
    //Your code   
}
```